# I am trying to figure out why my class payroll is not adding all the salaries properly....help me find the bug

Tags: java, class, static-methods, instance-variables, class-variables

So I am working on this Payroll class, I need to create two employees, hours worked and hourly pay and the calculate salaries. Finally, I have to add 10 extra hours to one of the previously created employees and calculate and display the total payroll. I wrote the two classes and everything works perfect, but when I look at the total Payroll it does not take into consideration the added hours.
The output for totalPayRoll should be $2000 after increasing the hours but i still get $1750!

```
public class PayRoll {

static double  getTotalPayRoll()
{
    return TotalPayRoll;

}


 public String employeeId;
 public int hoursWorked;
 public final double hourlyPay;
 private static double TotalPayRoll;
 private static double Salary;



 public PayRoll (String theEmployeeId, int theHoursWorked, 
                     double theHourlyPay)
 {
    this.employeeId = theEmployeeId;
    this.hoursWorked = theHoursWorked;
    this.hourlyPay = theHourlyPay;

    Salary = hoursWorked*hourlyPay;
    TotalPayRoll = TotalPayRoll + Salary ;

 }


 public String getTheEmployeeId()
 {
     return this.employeeId;
 }

 public int getTheHoursWorked()
 {
     return this.hoursWorked;
 }

 public double getTheHourlyPay()
 {
     return this.hourlyPay;
 }




 public double getSalary()
 {
     return PayRoll.Salary;
 }

 public void increase (int extraHours)
 {
     hoursWorked = (hoursWorked + extraHours);
 }


 public void changeTheHoursWorked (int amount)
 {
     hoursWorked = hoursWorked + amount;
 }

 public void calculateSalary() 
 {
     Salary = hoursWorked*hourlyPay;
 }

 public void calculateTotalPayRoll()
 {
     TotalPayRoll= TotalPayRoll+Salary;
 }

  public void changeHours(int newHours)
  {
      hoursWorked = newHours;
  }



}
```

And this is the main

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Date d = new Date();     
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance( DateFormat.MEDIUM ); 
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(); 

        System.out.println("\nPayroll For Week Ending " + df.format(d));
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
        PayRoll employee1 = new PayRoll("444-4444", 30, 25);
        employee1.calculateSalary();
        displaySalary(employee1, nf);

        PayRoll employee2 = new PayRoll("555-5555", 20, 50);
        employee2.calculateSalary();
        displaySalary(employee2, nf);

        System.out.println("Increase " + employee1.getTheEmployeeId() +
                              " by 10 hours");
        employee1.changeTheHoursWorked(10); // 10 hours increase
        employee1.calculateSalary();
        displaySalary(employee1, nf);

        System.out.println("Total payout amount.. " + 
                             nf.format(PayRoll.getTotalPayRoll()));

      }
      public static void displaySalary(PayRoll e, NumberFormat nf)  
      {
           System.out.println("Employee #: " + e.getTheEmployeeId());
           System.out.println("Hours Worked: " + e.getTheHoursWorked());
           System.out.println("Hourly Rate: " + e.getTheHourlyPay());
           System.out.println("Your Salary is: " + e.getSalary());


           System.out.println("---------------------------------\n");
       }

      }
```

Answer (score 2):

In your class :

```
private static double TotalPayRoll;
 private static double Salary;
```

Both are static members(class level members), so there will be only one copy of these members which will be shared among all the objects. Because *TotalPayRoll* and *salary* should be different for different payrolls so these should be non-static.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have static fields - make everything non-static

```
 private static double TotalPayRoll;  -> private double TotalPayRoll;
 private static double Salary;        -> private double Salary;
```

What is happening with static fields is

Firstly hoursWorked is set to 30

then 
hoursWorked is set to 20

then 
hoursWorked  is increased by 10

Comment: there are 2 different employees

Comment: BUT, the fields are static, that means there will only be one Object

Comment: so, first i set the 444 to 30 then increase by 10

Comment: so i don t need any static at all?

Comment: No static is needed or wanted

Answer (score 0):

Since you are declaring objects of your `PayRoll` class, you don't need to make an static members.

You can make your class like this

```
public class PayRoll {


//don't have to declare any member public since you have functions to return value
//don't need access specifier since they are private by default
 String employeeId;
 int hoursWorked;
 double hourlyPay;
 double TotalPayRoll=0;  //you have to initialize it to zero
 double Salary;



 public PayRoll (String theEmployeeId, int theHoursWorked, 
                     double theHourlyPay)
 {
    this.employeeId = theEmployeeId;
    this.hoursWorked = theHoursWorked;
    this.hourlyPay = theHourlyPay;

   // Salary = hoursWorked*hourlyPay;
   // TotalPayRoll = TotalPayRoll + Salary ;
   //you do not need to do this since you have different functions for them

 }

 public double  getTotalPayRoll()
{
    return this.TotalPayRoll;

}


 public String getTheEmployeeId()
 {
     return this.employeeId;
 }

 public int getTheHoursWorked()
 {
     return this.hoursWorked;
 }

 public double getTheHourlyPay()
 {
     return this.hourlyPay;
 }

 public double getSalary()
 {
     return this.Salary;
 }

//don't need the increase method 
 public void changeTheHoursWorked (int amount)
 {
     hoursWorked += amount;
 }

 public void calculateSalary() 
 {
     Salary = hoursWorked*hourlyPay;
 }

 public void calculateTotalPayRoll()
 {
     TotalPayRoll+=Salary;
 }

  //don't need the change hours function

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: //   System.out.println("Total payout amount.. " +  nf.format(PayRoll.getTotalPayRoll));